# NodeJs mssql multiple query inside loop and combine the result

Tags: jquery, sql, node.js, sql-server

I'm using nodejs `mssql` to get data.

For the single query, it's working perfect.

But now I have multiple query inside query in loop.

tbl_project:

```
id | name
1  | Temperature Monitoring
2  | General
```

and tbl_module:

```
id | name       | project_idfk
1  | Department | 2
2  | Report     | 1
```

- 

```
var session = 1;

request.query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id = '" + session + "'", function (err, result){
    request.query("SELECT P.id, P.name, P.code, AP.project_idfk, U.id AS user_id, U.username, U.group_idfk FROM tbl_project P, tbl_access_project AP, tbl_user U WHERE P.id = AP.project_idfk AND AP.group_idfk = U.group_idfk AND AP.group_idfk = '" + result['recordset'][0].group_idfk + "' AND U.id = '" + session + "' ORDER BY P.name ASC", function (err, result2){
        var project = result2['recordset']; //Project Name

        var output = [];
        for(var j = 0; j < result2['recordset'].length ; j++ ){
            tVal = result2['recordset'][j];
            (function(val){
                request.query("SELECT M.id, M.name, M.link, M.project_idfk, M.icon FROM tbl_module M WHERE M.project_idfk = '" + result2['recordset'][j].project_idfk + "' AND M.id IN(SELECT module_idfk FROM tbl_access_module WHERE group_idfk = '" + result2['recordset'][j].group_idfk + "' AND role IS NOT NULL AND(role = 'CREATE' OR role = 'VIEW'))", function (err, result3){
                output.push(result3['recordset']);    
            });
            })(tval);
        }

        res.json(project);
    });
});
```

The current result of json is:

```
[
{
  "id":2,
  "name":"General",
  "code":"GN",
  "project_idfk":2,
  "user_id":1,
  "username":"admin",
  "group_idfk":1
},
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"Temperature Monitoring",
  "code":"TM",
  "project_idfk":1,
  "user_id":1,
  "username":"admin",
  "group_idfk":1
}
]
```

What I expect the result is:

```
[
{
  "id":2,
  "name":"General",
  "code":"GN",
  "project_idfk":2,
  "user_id":1,
  "username":"admin",
  "group_idfk":1,
  "module":[{id:1, name: "Department"}] // Need to put the loop module here base on Project ID
},
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"Temperature Monitoring",
  "code":"TM",
  "project_idfk":1,
  "user_id":1,
  "username":"admin",
  "group_idfk":1
  "module":[{id:2, name: "Report"}]  // Need to put the loop module here base on Project ID
}
]
```

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2016 or later you can utilise [FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server) to write a single query that returns your entire JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Is not totally clear what are the relations between tables but seems that you forgot to setup the `module` property of `project` variable

```js
var session = 1;

request.query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id = '" + session + "'", function (err, result){
    request.query("SELECT P.id, P.name, P.code, AP.project_idfk, U.id AS user_id, U.username, U.group_idfk FROM tbl_project P, tbl_access_project AP, tbl_user U WHERE P.id = AP.project_idfk AND AP.group_idfk = U.group_idfk AND AP.group_idfk = '" + result['recordset'][0].group_idfk + "' AND U.id = '" + session + "' ORDER BY P.name ASC", function (err, result2){
        var project = result2['recordset']; //Project Name

        var output = [];
        for(var j = 0; j < result2['recordset'].length ; j++ ){
            tVal = result2['recordset'][j];
            (function(val){
                request.query("SELECT M.id, M.name, M.link, M.project_idfk, M.icon FROM tbl_module M WHERE M.project_idfk = '" + result2['recordset'][j].project_idfk + "' AND M.id IN(SELECT module_idfk FROM tbl_access_module WHERE group_idfk = '" + result2['recordset'][j].group_idfk + "' AND role IS NOT NULL AND(role = 'CREATE' OR role = 'VIEW'))", function (err, result3){
                // output.push(result3['recordset']);    
                project.module = result3['recordset'];
                output.push(project);
            });
            })(tval);
        }

        res.json(project);
    });
});
```